# Grunt task killing server when complete

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, gruntjs

I am building a app where Grunt compiles a file that is returned back to the user as a download.

If I already had a static file, the I could just do:

```
app.post('/', function(req, res){
    var pkgFile = __dirname + '/myfile.js';
    var filestream = fs.createReadStream(pkgFile);
    filestream.pipe(res);
});
```

The problem is if the file is compiled by Grunt, called from inside `app.post()` and when the Grunt task is done it exits my express server. I get a messade "Done, without errors" and with that the process exits.

I am running my Grunt task using Grunt.cli and passing a callback to my packager since my Grunt task returns data, no files written.

```
grunt.cli({
    gruntfile: __dirname + "/../gruntfile.js",
    modules: modules,
    strip: !compat,
    releaseVersion: version,
    project: project,
    noCoreDependencies: !addCoreDependencies,
    callback: stream
});

function stream (data) {
    var filename = ['MooTools-', project, '-', version, (compat ? '-compat' : '') + (minified ? '-compressed' : ''), '.js'].join('');
    if (minified) data = uglify(data);

    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/javascript');
    res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=' + filename);
    res.write(data, 'binary');
    res.end();
}
```

This way everything works **one time**, then I have to re-start the server...

Is there a way I can run Grunt.cli as a child process, or in a way that it exits without killing my server, **and** being able to have that callback as a parameter into grunt options?

Or is there a better way to design this?

---

What I am doing is compiling different files from a library into one `.js` file > uglifying it > providing as download to user.

[My Gruntfile:](https://github.com/SergioCrisostomo/website/blob/fix-builder/gruntfile.js)

```
"use strict";

module.exports = function(grunt) {

    require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);

    var cb = grunt.option('callback'),
        strip = grunt.option('strip'),
        version = grunt.option('releaseVersion'),
        modules = grunt.option('modules'),
        project = grunt.option('project'),
        noCoreDependencies = grunt.option('noCoreDependencies');

    function projectPath(project_, version_){
        var versions = require('./package.json')._projects[project_].versions;
        if (!~versions.indexOf(version_)) version_ = versions.filter(function(ver){
            return ver.slice(0, -2) <= version_.slice(0, -2); 
        })[0];
        return 'cache/' + project_.toLowerCase() + '/docs/' + project_.toLowerCase() + '-' + version + '/Source/';
    }

    var packagerOptions = {
        options: {
            name: {
                Core: projectPath('core', version),
                More: projectPath('more', version)
            },
            callback: cb,
            noOutput: true,
            ignoreYAMLheader: noCoreDependencies
        },
        customBuild: {
            src: [projectPath('core', version) + '**/*.js', projectPath('more', version) + '**/*.js'],
            dest: 'mootools-rocks!.js'
        }
    }

    if (modules.length) packagerOptions.options.only = modules;
    if (strip) packagerOptions.options.strip = ['.*compat'];

    grunt.initConfig({
        'packager': packagerOptions
    });

    grunt.registerTask('default', 'build file and don\'t exit', function(){
        grunt.task.run(['packager:customBuild']);
        // how to prevent process.exit() ?
    });
};
```

Comment: That's the way of Grunt. Gulp works by stream without disk

Comment: What type is the file that you are processing?

Comment: What is your Gruntfile please?

Comment: @Vinz243 updated. (will delete this comment when you have read it)

Comment: @parchment updated. Basically compiling different files from a library into 1 .js file > uglifying it > providing as download to user.

Comment: @Sergio Deleting means no-one else can read and have the information.

Comment: @Scimonster, I added in the question instead. That is what I meant, just to keep the commments clean.

Comment: You should try using this: https://github.com/rma4ok/grunt-bg-shell
Basically, it creates a child process for your grunt tasks. You'll be able to run these tasks from your server and they won't kill the parent process when they complete.

Comment: @Etai thank you for your input. I need a callback function for my packager and I don't think I can do that via shell.

Comment: You can specify a done callback there.

How are you running grunt from express? Can you post a snippet?

Comment: @Etai, I'm running `grunt.cli()` inside `app.post()` [like this](https://github.com/SergioCrisostomo/website/blob/fix-builder/builder/index.js#L33).

Comment: I'm pretty sure a child process is the answer.
Check out how grunt watch works: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch/blob/master/tasks/lib/taskrun.js

Each time the task is run from the watcher, they spawn a new child process with grunt.util.spawn, setting grunt:true to run the grunt bin (instead of using some command) and pass it args.

I think this is a good pattern for you to use, instead of grunt.cli

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61793/discussion-between-etai-and-sergio).

Comment: I'm quite sure that `grunt.cli` is the wrong call - there must be a way to trigger a grunt task run without an exit. But: you can start a child and call the `grunt.cli` inside it. Then as a callback give `child.send` and in the parent react on `on('message',...)`.

Comment: @CFrei thank you for looking at this! If I use `on('message, fn)` what will that collect? will the grunt log be passed there also? i am sceptic to a "catch all" idea. Or did I understand you wrong?

Comment: Uh, I don't know about grunt (log), `on('message', fn)` will catch everything you send with `mychild.send()`. So, if you can send something like `{log: log, data: data}`, the answer is yes :)

Comment: I know it isn't a real solution but i run my scripts with forever : https://github.com/nodejitsu/forever